Looking for an example of a real (hyper)cubic surface with special restriction
Need help looking for an example of a cubic surface over $\mathbf{R}$: it has two connected components, one of the components is convex. Here's my thoughts so far:

The model in my head is the elliptic curve $y^2=x(x-1)(x+1)$, which has two components (frankly speaking I do not know if the author means connected components in Zariski topology or Euclidean topology).
I guess one cannot find such a surface in $\mathbf{R}^3$ because of the requirement of being convex, which says that if two points lie in $X_0$, then the segment connecting these two points lie in $X_0$ too. In other words I may have to look for a hypersurface of dimension $\ge 3$. Sadly this will not be easily visualisable.

Any help will be appreciated. In case it may help I am attaching the context and notations.

The example is mentioned in Cubic Forms by Yuri Manim. In section 11 he wanted to show that admissible equivalence relations can non-trivial by giving this example.


Example 11.9. Let $k=\mathbf{R}$ and $V$ a cubic surface over $\mathbf{R}$ such that $V(\mathbf{R})$ consists of two connected components $X_0$ and $X_1$ and such that $X_0$ is convex. Then this partitioning into components is admissible and the $CML(X_0,X_1)$ with zero element $X_0$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}_2$.


Let $k$ be an infinite field and $F$ a form of the third degree which is irreducible over the algebraic closure of $k$. A hypersurface $V$ is given by $F(T_0,\dots,T_n)=0$ where $(T_0,\dots,T_n)$ is a homogeneous coordinate system in some projecrive spaces over $k$. The set $V_r(k)$ will be the set of non-singular $k$-points of the cubic hypersurface $V \subset \mathbf{P}^n$.

Let $P$ be a set and $L \subset P \times P \times P$ a three-place relation which is symmetric (i.e. invariant under all the permutations of $x,y,z$ and "solvable", i.e. whenever $x \in P$ and $y \in P$, there is always $z \in P$ such that $L(x,y,z)$ is satisfiable. (In the book the relation is essentially collinearity of three points).

An equivalence relation $R\subset P \times P$ is admissible (w.r.t. $L$) if $L/R$ induces a symmetric quasigroup composition law on $P/R$. (This is to ensure the unicity of the third point $z$ in the sense of collinearity). Therefore $(X_0,X_1)$ in example 11.9 makes sense.

A set $G$ with a binary composition law $G \times G \to G$ by $(x,y) \to x \circ y$ is called a symmetric quasigroup if there exists a three-place relation $L(x,y,z):x \circ y = z$ is invariant under all the permutations of $x,y,z$ and $x \circ y = y \circ x$, $x \circ (x \circ y)=y$ for all $x,y,z \in G$. (This rings a bell of elliptic curve automatically).

A symmetric quasigroup $G$ is called Abelian if for any element $u \in G$, the composition law $xy = u \circ (x \circ y)$ turns $G$ into an abelian group (this is the case for ellitpic curves)

A CH-quasigroup (Cubic-Hypersurface) is a symmetric quasigroup in which any three elements generate an Abelian quasigroup.

A set $G$ with a composition law $(x,y) \mapsto xy$ is called a commutative Moufang loop (CML) if 1) $xy=yx$ for all $x,y \in G$; 2) there exists $u \in G$ such that $ux=x$ for all $x \in G$; 3) there exists a map $E \to E:x \mapsto x^{-1}$ such that $x^{-1}(xy)=y$ for all $x,y \in E$; 4) for all $x,y,z \in G$, we have $x(xy)=x^2yz$, $(xy)(xz)=x^2(yz)$ and $x(y(xz))=(x^2y)z$.

A CH-quasigroup becomes a CML by taking $xy=u \circ (x \circ y)$.

Let $S$ be an admissible relation on $V_r(k)$ and $E=V_r(k)/S$. Then $E$ is a CH-quasigroup and therefore it makes sense to write $CML E = V_r(k)/S$ and thus $CML(X_0,X_1)$ in example 11.9 makes sense.


